# Unable to make a connection to Dockerized MongoDb server - bind ip - No Chance to Authorize

Tags: mongodb, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

Background:

I am using a "custom" dockerfile (just a modified versino of [this](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/274966255b326b17a4a351867ece4eaa0eefef28/4.0/Dockerfile)) to setup my MongoDB server as well as a docker-compose file to link my dockerized Asp.Net Core application to the mongodb docker container.

Issue:

I got this error:

```
mongodb          | 2018-07-09T17:28:24.327+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: This server is bound to localhost.
mongodb          | 2018-07-09T17:28:24.327+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server.
mongodb          | 2018-07-09T17:28:24.327+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Start the server with --bind_ip <address> to specify which IP
mongodb          | 2018-07-09T17:28:24.327+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to
mongodb          | 2018-07-09T17:28:24.327+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the
mongodb          | 2018-07-09T17:28:24.327+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning.
```

I tried using bind-ip in my docker-compose file but then when I try to connect using the IP, Robo3T just times out and says "Failed to connect to {ip}:{port} - No chance to authorize"

If I do just:

```
command: --bind_ip 127.0.0.1
```

Then the error goes away but I still can't make a connection from Robo3T to the database

Docker Compose File

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  sensormonitor:
    container_name: sensormonitor
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    environment:
      - NODE_PATH=Production
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
    links:
      - mongodb
    depends_on:
      - mongodb

  mongodb:
    #image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongodb
    environment:
      - MONGO_DATA_DIR=/data/db
      - MONGO_LOG_DIR=/dev/null
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=SensorMonitorDb
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=123ewq
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    #volumes:
    #  - ./data:/data/db:rw
    build:
      context: ./Scripts/Mongodb/MongoDbDocker
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.mongodb
    #command: --bind_ip 127.0.0.1,0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Why --bind_ip 127.0.0.1,0.0.0.0?

If you put --bind_ip 0.0.0.0 then it can listen on all the interfaces (including 127.0.0.1)

Comment: because every other IP address I tried seems to be unavailable and causes mongodb to exit

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem? I am having a seemingly similar issue with dovecot director.

Answer (score 0):

By default mongo container opens for all interfaces(i.e, --bind_ip_all/--bind_ip 0.0.0.0(mutual exclusive)).

```
shakeel@airflow:~/docker-space/mongo$ sudo docker exec -it mongo_mongodb_1 bash
root@airflow:/# ps -ef|grep mongo
mongodb      1     0  3 20:24 ?        00:00:01 mongod --bind_ip_all
root        65    55  0 20:24 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mongo
root@airflow:/#
```

`network_mode: "host"` is the configuration you need to connect mongo without container IP(docker-compose version 3.7).

```
shakeel@airflow:~/docker-space/mongo$ cat docker-compose.yml 
version: '3.7'
services:
  # MongoDB: https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:4
    network_mode: "host"
    volumes:
      - mongo-db-data:/data/db

# Volumes for persisting data, see https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/
volumes:
  mongo-db-data:
```